# Able to git clone into Mobaxterm, but missing permissions to download into my PC

Tags: git, mobaxterm

I want to git clone a repo (from Gitlab) into Mobaxterm and then later download a specific file from the clone from Mobaxterm into my PC.

I am able to git clone --recursive [HTTP]. But when I try to access the cloned directory through Mobaxterm's SSH Browser (I can access it with 'cd', but not by clicking on it in the SSH Browser), it returns 'SFTP error #3: Permission denied'.

I tried copying the specific file I want to download into an accessible directory, but when I try to download it I get 'Error #3: Permission denied' and 'Error #2: No such file'.

Can someone help me be able to download from the cloned repo? Thank you!